# Как получить разницу между двумя датами в годах, месяцах и днях?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Есть две даты:

```
date1 = 20201231
date2 = 20311105
```

Как получить разницу между ними в виде:

```
d_years = date2-date1
d_months = date2-date1
d_days = date2-date1
print(f'delta : \n in days {d_days}\n in months {d_months}\n in years {d_years}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь удобным модулем [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as du_parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

d1 = du_parse(str(date1))
d2 = du_parse(str(date2))
delta = relativedelta(d2, d1)
```

---

```
In [14]: delta.years
Out[14]: 10

In [15]: delta.months
Out[15]: 10

In [16]: delta.days
Out[16]: 5
```

**общее число месяцев:**

```
In [76]: delta.years * 12 + delta.months
Out[76]: 130
```

**точное общее число дней** - для этого достаточно воспользоваться атрибутом `.days` от разницы дат:

```
In [78]: (d2 - d1).days
Out[78]: 3961
```

---

Примеры использования парсера:

```
In [68]: du_parse('20200509')
Out[68]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 0, 0)

In [69]: du_parse('2020-05-09')
Out[69]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 0, 0)

In [70]: du_parse('2020/05/09 11:12:13')
Out[70]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 11, 12, 13)

In [71]: du_parse('Tuesday 5 May 2020')
Out[71]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 5, 0, 0)
```

По умолчанию, если первое число <=12, то оно воспринимается как месяц, т.е. из `09.05.2020` - получим `5 сентября 2020`:

```
In [72]: du_parse('09.05.2020')
Out[72]: datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 5, 0, 0)
```

Можно явно указать, что первое число - это дни:

```
In [74]: du_parse('09.05.2020', dayfirst=True)
Out[74]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 0, 0)
```

Comment: а как заставить его воспринимать значение YYYYMMDD без разделителей?

Comment: `dateutil.parser.parse()` - сама подбирает правильный формат даты. Но на вход ей нужно предавать строку, а не число

Comment: как посчитать сколько месяцев между '20201231' и '20311105' с помощью этого модуля? тут по идее 131 месяцев, а если по примеру выше, пишет 10

Comment: @Андрей, `delta.years * 12 + delta.months` и их таки 130 ;)

Comment: а можно это в ответ добавить? и да я таки обсчитался, в голове считать сложнее) Правда такой расчет не даст точное количество дней,, только если банковские 30 дней воткнуть.

Comment: @Андрей, добавил :)