# Как получить разницу между двумя датами в формате N лет Y месяцев X дней с учетом повышающих и понижающих коэффициентов

Tags: python

Использовал модуль dateutil.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as du_parse   
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date1 = '2021.06.07'
date2 = '2022.06.07'
d1 = du_parse(str(date1))
d2 = du_parse(str(date2))
delta = (relativedelta(d2, d1))*2
print(delta.years)
print(delta.months)
print(delta.days)
```

При использовании в качестве коэффициента целых чисел проблем не возникает. При использовании вещественных чисел расчет разницы между датами происходит не корректно

Comment: Что такое «повышающие коэффициенты» ?

Comment: Применяются при расчете стажа работы. Некоторые периоды могут засчитываться как 1 день за 2 дня, 1 день за 1,5 дня, а некоторые периоды засчитываются за половину т.е с коэффициентом 0,5

Comment: Так вы добавьте использование ваших этих коэффициентов в код. Иначе вообще непонятно, что мы, собственно, обсуждаем. И ещё откуда взялось `du_parse`, где импорт для этой функции?

Comment: Код поправил. Добавил коэф. 2 в переменную delta. С целыми числами все работает так как надо. Если вместо целого числа использовать вещественное, например 0,5 то результат будет 0 0 0. А должен быть 0 6 0

Comment: Теперь понятна суть вопроса. Ну, видимо, тогда нужно всё-таки `d2-d1` умножать. Но как потом это в годы и т.д. переводить непонятно - ведь так теряется привязка к конкретному году и непонятно, сколько точно дней в таком году. Тут только вручную примерно переводить дни в месяцы и годы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить разницу между двумя датами в годах, месяцах и днях?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122715/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, смотрите, если вы готовое значение `relativedelta` на что-то умножаете, то как вы можете получить корректное число лет, месяцев и дней **в принципе**? Точное число лет и месяцев можно вычислить только между **конкретными датами**, что и делает `relativedelta`. Как только вы начинаете производить какие-то действия с полученными значениями, сразу становится непонятно, как их интерпретировать. Между конкретными датами понятно, сколько дней в каком месяце. А если у вас абстрактное число дней, то как его перевести в годы и месяцы - ведь вы не знаете, **какие именно** это годы и месяцы, **сколько в них дней**. Всё, что можно в таком случае сделать - это вычислить число дней между датами и умножить его на ваш коэффициент, это легко:

```
delta = (d2 - d1) * 0.5
print(delta.days)
# 180
```

**Корректно** перевести полученное число дней в месяцы и годы **нельзя**. Можно только как-то приблизительно это сделать, разделив на **среднее** число дней в месяце и в году.

Answer (score 1):

Можно рассмотреть такой подход. Вычисляем дельты между двумя датами, получаем `datetime.timedelta`. Который умножаем на коэффициент и прибавляем к первой дате. Тем самым получаем гипотетическую дату в будущем `d3 = d1 + (d2 - d1) * koeff`, как если бы стаж был длиннее в `коэффициент` раз. После чего получаем разность между полученной (третьей) датой и первой датой. В этом случае даты получаются совершенно конкретные, с конкретными високосными и невисокосными годами, конкретным кол-вом дней в конкретных месяцах.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as du_parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date1 = '2021.06.07'
date2 = '2022.06.10'
d1 = du_parse(str(date1))
d2 = du_parse(str(date2))

koeff = 1.7
d3 = d1 + (d2 - d1) * koeff  # datetime.timedelta * koeff

delta = relativedelta(d2, d1)
delta_koeff = relativedelta(d3, d1)

print(f'Натурально: {delta.years} лет, {delta.months} месяцев, {delta.days} дней')
print(f'С коэфф. {koeff}: {delta_koeff.years} лет, {delta_koeff.months} месяцев, {delta_koeff.days} дней')
```

```
Натурально: 1 лет, 0 месяцев, 3 дней
С коэфф. 1.7: 1 лет, 8 месяцев, 15 дней
```

Comment: Да, хорошая мысль, я как-то не додумал до неё )  Хотя на самом деле непонятно, что там через эти коэффициенты собственно хочет автор вопроса посчитать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Попробую разобраться. По поводу для чего это. В начале 2000-х встречал программу для расчета выслуги лет сотрудников МВД. В ней стаж работы считался корректно, в том числе с применением различных коэффициентов. Недавно начал самостоятельно изучать pyhton и чисто для практики решил сделать что-то подобное.